# Proving that a graph has a complete circle?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph that is Connected, un-directed and all of its vertices have even degree. So does this kind of graph have at least one complete circle?

A complete circle is a circle that passes in all edges only once.

I have a feeling that it's true. I'm trying to prove this by induction, however I'm getting stuck at some point. I'll be very happy if someone can help and show me how to prove this.

Comment: Hint: Take any circle in the graph. If it passes through all the vertices, you're done. Otherwise, the remaining edges form a graph which has almost the same property (although it might not be connected) and take any circle from it. Show that these two circles can be combined into one. Rinse, repeat :-)

Answer (score 1):

look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path or just in any graph theory textbook search for Eulerian circuit.